# How to compute the continued fraction to a generic step by Mathematica?

Tags: manipulate, programming

I am reading the article "Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of spin-weighted spheroidal harmonics
in four and higher dimensions", which is on https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0511111.
I want to derive the formula (2.15), (2.16) in this article. To do that, we need to solve the continued fractions equation (2.12), which is
\begin{equation}
\beta_r-\frac{\alpha_{r-1} \gamma_r}{\beta_{r-1}-} \frac{\alpha_{r-2} \gamma_{r-1}}{\beta_{r-2}-} \ldots \frac{\alpha_0 \gamma_1}{\beta_0}=\frac{\alpha_r \gamma_{r+1}}{\beta_{r+1}-} \frac{\alpha_{r+1} \gamma_{r+2}}{\beta_{r+2}-} \ldots \tag 1
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_p, \beta_p, \gamma_p$ is in (2.8). To derive formula (2.15), (2.16), firstly we need to compute the left hand side of (1). However, in most cases Mathematica is used to solve numerical problems. Since **r is a symbol**, I don't know how to write a code to compute the left hand side of (1).

Comment: "in most cases Mathematica is used to solve numerical problems". Not quite right.  *Mathematica* is provably the most sophisticated, complete, and accurate software system for solving *symbolic* equations.

Comment: A notation question I can't figure out yet from the paper : 
  what are the minus' s in the denominator (e . g . $\beta _ {r - 
         2} - $)?Are the denominator terms being subtracted while the
numerator terms are multiplied?

Comment: There was an obvious missing "-" typo in equation (2.12). Also, $r$ is a small but fixed integer.

Comment: If you check the documentation for FromContinuedFraction (ref/FromContinuedFraction), and look under Detials, the second bullet point states that the arguments passed as a list to the function can be symbolic. So as long as you can construct a list with the arguments you want in the correct order, the built-in function should do what you want. Even so, won't you have to cut off your seiies somewhere? You can't set up an infinite number of terms, so won't there be a maximum value for r?

Comment: **However, in most cases Mathematica is used to solve numerical problems**. I think you are confusing Mathematica with Matlab when saying this

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mathematica function `ContinuedFractionK[]` you can
try experimenting with code something like this:

```
(* k_+, k_- *)
kp = Abs[m + s]/2; km = Abs[m - s]/2;

(* _sA_{lm} equation (2.13) *)
M = 3; (* an example *)
f[0] = l(l+1) - s(s+1);
Aslm = Sum[ f[p]c^p, {p, 0, M-1}] + O[c]^M ;

(* define the three sequences *)
\[Alpha][p_] := -2 (p + 1) (p + 2 km + 1);
\[Beta][p_] := p (p - 1) + 2 p (km + kp + 1 - 2 c) -
   (2 c (2 km + s + 1) - (km + kp) (km + kp + 1)) -
   (c^2 + s (s + 1) + Aslm);
\[Gamma][p_] := 2 c (p + km + kp + s); 

(* left side of of equation (2.12) *)
cf[r_] :=  (a[0] / ContinuedFractionK[a[i], b[i], {i, 0, r}]) /.
  {b[n_] -> \[Beta][r - n], 
   a[n_] -> -\[Alpha][r - n]*\[Gamma][r - n + 1]}];

(* Simple example for r=3 *)
cf[3]
```

This is just a start. There is a lot more work to get the results
that are in the arXiv article linked to.

Comment: Your code is like the code in Mathematica package "SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics.m", which is link to https://bhptoolkit.org/SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics/.

Comment: But I don't know how to get the series expansion coefficients in "SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics.m".

Comment: @amonxu You commented "But I don't know how to get the series expansion coefficients in ..." but that is another question. I suggest asking a new question about that. Did you read the documentation that comes with it?

Comment: I read SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics.m package. I don't know why the  series expansion coefficients in SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics.m take that forms.

Comment: @amonxu I suggest that this is a question you may want to ask about on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @-Somos Thank you for your help!