# How to compute the infinite continued fraction?

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, manipulate, programming

I am reading the article "Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of spin-weighted spheroidal harmonics in four and higher dimensions", which is on https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0511111.
I want to derive the formulas (2.16a)-(2.16g) in this article. To do that, we need to solve the continued fractions equation (2.12), which is
$$
\beta_r-\frac{\alpha_{r-1} \gamma_r}{\beta_{r-1}-} \frac{\alpha_{r-2} \gamma_{r-1}}{\beta_{r-2}-} \ldots \frac{\alpha_0 \gamma_1}{\beta_0}=\frac{\alpha_r \gamma_{r+1}}{\beta_{r+1}-} \frac{\alpha_{r+1} \gamma_{r+2}}{\beta_{r+2}-} \ldots \tag 1
$$
However, there are infinite terms in the right hand side of Eq. (1).
How to compute this continued fraction? I find the package "SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics.m" is useful for solving this problem. But, there are still some problems, for example it can't run to end.
The code is as follows:

```
kp = Abs[m + s]/2; km = Abs[m - s]/2;
CF[a_, b_, {n_, n0_}] := 
    Module[{A, B, ak, bk, res = Indeterminate, j = n0},
      A[n0 - 2] = 1;
      B[n0 - 2] = 0;
      ak[k_] := ak[k] = (a /. n -> k);
      bk[k_] := bk[k] = (b /. n -> k);
      A[n0 - 1] = 0(*bk[n0-1]*);
      B[n0 - 1] = 1;
      A[k_] := A[k] = bk[k] A[k - 1] + ak[k] A[k - 2];
      B[k_] := B[k] = bk[k] B[k - 1] + ak[k] B[k - 2];
      While[res =!= (res = A[j]/B[j]), j++];
      res
      ](*Compute the infinite continued fraction*);
l = 7; s = 1; m = 1;(*It seems that a specific value for l, s, m needs to be given in advance*)
nInv = l - Abs[m];
\[Alpha][p_] := -2 (p + 1) (p + 2 km + 1);
\[Beta][p_, A_] := 
  p (p - 1) + 
   2 p (km + kp + 1 - 
      2 c) - (2 c (2 km + s + 1) - (km + kp) (km + kp + 1)) - (c^2 + 
     s (s + 1) + A);
\[Gamma][p_] := 2 c (p + km + kp + s);    
LHS = \[Beta][nInv, Ax] + 
   ContinuedFractionK[-\[Alpha][nInv - i] \[Gamma][
      nInv - i + 1], \[Beta][nInv - i, Ax], {i, 1, nInv}];
RHS = -CF[-\[Alpha][i - 1] \[Gamma][i], \[Beta][i, Ax], {i, 
     nInv + 1}];
Eq = LHS - RHS;
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287789/how-to-compute-the-continued-fraction-to-a-generic-step-by-mathematica)?

Comment: @Domen Now I want to compute the right hand side of Eq. (1). But, because of infinite terms, I don't know how to handle it.